# How can I add elements to an Array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I am writting a program to get a list of cities and their GPS coordinates and store it in an Array  named "cities", to worjk later with it. This is the fragment of code:

```
var city = {name:String,lat:Number,lon:Number};
var cities = Array.of(city);

city.name="London";
city.lat=51.50;
city.lon=-0,11;

cities.push(city);

city.name="Barcelona";
city.lat=41.38;
city.lon=2,15;

cities.push(city);

console.log("Number of cities "+cities.length);
console.log(cities);
```

The result when executing this code is the following:

```
Number of cities 3
[
  { name: 'Barcelona', lat: 41.38, lon: 2 },
  { name: 'Barcelona', lat: 41.38, lon: 2 },
  { name: 'Barcelona', lat: 41.38, lon: 2 }
]
```

That is, it seems that the "push" method **overwrites all the array records**, and also add an additional record. I also have declared the array cities as follows:
var cities = [city]; // An array of elements of the class "city"
var cities = [];
with both declarations the result is the same.

That's very strange and it seems obvious, but I do not know what's happening..

¿What am I doing wrong in the code shown above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you observe has nothing to do with the `push()` function or the array. Instead, it is the way JavaScript handles all objects: by reference.

To clone an object, in other words break the reference, you can use a call such as

- `city = {...city}; // spread`
- `city = Object.assign({}, city);`
- `city = jQuery.extend({}, city);`

The problem you have is that when changing the properties within the `city` object, you modify the references already in the array at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `city` object is being **passed by reference**. The object in your array will be pointing to the same instance, so modifying it will modify all instances of that object in the array: regardless of how many times it's being inserted.

What you can do is to create a function that returns a fresh object:

```js
function getCity(name, lat, long) {
  return { name, lat, long };
}

const cities = [];

cities.push(getCity('London', 51.50, 0.11));
cities.push(getCity('Barcelona', 41.38, 2.15));

console.log("Number of cities " + cities.length);
console.log(cities);
```

Alternatively, just create the objects in place:

```js
function getCity(name, lat, long) {
  return { name, lat, long };
}

const cities = [];

cities.push({
  name: 'London',
  lat: 51.50,
  long: -0.11
});
cities.push({
  name: 'Barbelona',
  lat: 41.38,
  long: 2.15
});

console.log("Number of cities " + cities.length);
console.log(cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you very much!!** it was a beginner's mistake....the way how javascript manage objects, and nothing to do with the push() method.

I have used  a class and a constructor and instantiate a new "fresh" object like this and it works !!. Here is the code:

```
class City {
    constructor(name, lat,lon) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
    }
    };

var cities = [];

var newcity = new City("London",51.50,-0.11);

cities.push(newcity);

var newcity = new City("Barcelona",41.38,2.15);

cities.push(newcity);

var newcity = new City("Rome",41.90,12.49);

cities.push(newcity);

console.log("Number of cities "+cities.length);
console.log(cities);
```

and the result correct:

```
Number of cities 3
[
  City { name: 'London', lat: 51.5, lon: -0.11 },
  City { name: 'Barcelona', lat: 41.38, lon: 2.15 },
  City { name: 'Rome', lat: 41.9, lon: 12.49 }
]
```